# How to populate lookup tables in Rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, cucumber, factory-bot

I am using **Cucumber**, **RSpec**, and **Factory Girl** for the testing of my Rails application. But I have several lookup tables that contain mostly **static** data. So I'm trying to figure out the best way to populate these when testing. Doing them individually in `FactoryGirl` seems tedious and I'd like to stay away from fixtures. For development and production, I populate them in my `seeds.rb` file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Factory Girl .sequence, [Populator](https://github.com/ryanb/populator) and [Faker](https://github.com/westarete/faker) and you'll never run out of lab rats!

```
Factory.define(:model) do |m|
  m.sequence(:title)  { |n| "model-#{n}" }
  m.author            Faker::Name.name
  m.short             Populator.words(5)
  m.long              Populator.paragraphs(1..3)
end
```

Then maybe in a `before :each` block

```
@models = []
15.times { @models << Factory.create(:model) }
```

Or you can use only Populator to fill your database before tests.

Comment: Syntax for FactoryGirl changed a bit with new updates: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
rake RAILS_ENV=test db:seed
```

in your test helper file?