# With RSpec, how to seed the database on load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using rspec for testing w my rails 3 app. I need to seed the database before the tests start. How can I seed the database with the following:

**/db/seeds.rb**

```
["Admin", "Member"].each do |role_name|
  Role.find_or_create_by_name(role_name)
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try, something like this

```
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
```

You can get a list of all rake commands doing

```
rake -T
```

If this is test data, you may want to look at putting it into fixtures which will be loaded on the start of the tests.

Comment: This will seed data for the development database, not the test database.  Add RAILS_ENV=test to seed the test database.

Answer (score 214):

In spec_helper.rb or rails_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    Rails.application.load_seed # loading seeds
  end
end
```

Comment: I needed to explicitly add the 'database_cleaner' gem to my `:test` group in my gemfile to get DatabaseCleaner working.

Comment: This worked great for me and now I'm wondering why it's not gotten more upvotes or shown up elsewhere

Comment: Not requiring another gem when using the basic seeding functionality is much nicer with this.

Comment: Works for me after I added to `rails_helper.rb` instead of `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: How do i use this to add a different seeds file besides the main seeds file?  I'd like a much smaller one for my tests

Comment: Hi @JeremyMoritz I would do this in similar way like here explained https://medium.com/@ethanryan/split-your-rails-seeds-file-into-separate-files-in-different-folders-3c57be765818 . I hope this will help out.

Answer (score 24):

However Scott's solution surely works for you, I believe the better way to solve your problem was to put the code responsible for seeding your test database within RSpec's configure block:

I use SeedFu and in my spec_helper I have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # some other configuration code ...

  config.before(:suite) do
    # ...
    SeedFu.seed
    # ...
  end

  # some other configuration code ...

end
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in rails_helper rather than spec_helper?

Answer (score 12):

I've followed the raging debate over at [Auto-load the seed data from db/seeds.rb with rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386604/auto-load-the-seed-data-from-db-seeds-rb-with-rake).  Die-hards maintain that you should never load seed data for tests, but I take the more moderate stance that there are occasions where you might want to load seed data **for specific tests**, e.g. verifying that the seed data exists.

Unlike some answers given here, I do **not** recommend unconditionally loading the seeds from inside your spec_helper file.  Instead, you can load your seeds using `before :each` or `before :all` inside just those test files that need the seeds, e.g.:

```
describe "db seed tests" do
  before(:each) do
    load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb" 
  end

  ...your test code here...
end
```

#### update

As @marzapower points out, if you go this route, your seeds.db file should clear each table before creating entries or use `find_or_create_by` methods.  (Hint: the former is faster and more reliable.)  This will prevent duplicate entries if you load the seeds.db file more than once.

Comment: This approach only works for the first call after a `db:reset`. Every sequent call will duplicate data.

Comment: @marzapower: Good catch -- I should have mentioned that my seeds.db file always drops the tables before populating them for the very reason you mention.  Alternately, the seeds.db file can use `find_or_create` to avoid creating duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

To load seeds in rspec you need to add it after database cleanup in confg.before(:suite) in spec_helper

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  load Rails.root.join('db', 'seeds.rb')
end
```

Comment: +1 to this way, it allows to load a different seed file for test (perhaps smaller ;)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up needing to use DatabaseCleaner to truncate the database, then load the rake task that does my seeding (because I use [seedbank](https://github.com/james2m/seedbank)). After that, I wound up wrapping my tests in a transaction like on the [database_cleaner README](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner), so that each test could run with a freshly loaded site.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    MyApplicationName::Application.load_tasks
    Rake::Task['db:seed'].invoke # loading seeds
  end
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```