# Seed-like records in rspec and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I know that seeding test database is a kind of [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386604/auto-load-the-seed-data-from-db-seeds-rb-with-rake).
I need to test [Stripe](https://stripe.com) api communication in my model tests. I know that external requests in Unit tests is a bad idea too, but nevertheless.

The stripe account has static subscription plan names. So when I test functionality linked with Stripe I need to take them from my database. I use Factory girl gem as a fixture source, but since I need only particular names for Stripe plans I hardcoded them to the factory:

```
  factory :subscription_type do
    name "Personal"
    frequency "month"
    stripe_plan_id "personal"
  end
```

Other factories that uses this one is trying to create each time new object with the same field values and due to validation of uniqueness on the subscription_type model, the factories throw errors. I would prefer if they all use the same record (if exists) if called in one example.

What is the best practice here, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `sequence(:unique_field) {|n| "unique_field #{n}"}`, this will make a variable `n` with order, then field would be unique.

Comment: It is not uniqueness I care about: I need technically the opposite.

Comment: I need only one instance of subscription_type object across all factories. So they don't create each time new unique subscription_type

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have only one subscription_type object, try creating it first, and passing it as a parameter for the other factories:

```
@subscription_type = FactoryGirl.create :subscription_type

@other_object = FactoryGirl.create :other_object, subscription_type: @subscription_type
```

You could also try to define a smart relation for your factory where it checks if there is a subscription type before:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :user do
      subscription_type { SubscriptionType.first.present? ? SubscriptionType.first : FactoryGirl.create(:subscription_type) }
    end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that will solve the problem, but the price is little bit high: you have to care about uniqueness of @subscription_type through tests yourself. I was hoping of factory-level solution

Comment: Yeah, that is simple and seems to be a solve. Silly me, thanks will tryout.