# With Capybara, how to seed the database on load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Testing one of the web app using capybara and learnt a lot about how to write test cases. Wanted to know if there is any such way to load the seeds data before the start of each test case.

I have tried writing

```
Rails.application.load_seed
```

inside my '**./features/support/env.rb**' but no luck. Any expert out there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-load the seed data from db/seeds.rb with rake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386604/auto-load-the-seed-data-from-db-seeds-rb-with-rake)